# Changing application.properties name in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've got my `application.properties` file in /resources. I just want to change the name to `<my-project-name>.properties`. According to [this reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config), I should be able to change the name by specifying spring.config.name as an environment property:

`java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.name=myproject`

But is there a way I can do this with an annotation or within my codebase somehow?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What I believe to be the most simple way to do this is to set a system property in the main method of your Spring Boot application entry point:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tell Boot to look for my-project.properties instead of application.properties
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "my-project");
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that if your config file is in another folder you can set the location as well:
`System.setProperty("spring.config.location", "../config/");`

Answer (score 2):

```
spring.config.location - classpath:{myproject}.properties
```

It's worked for me.

And make sure the same classpath is be placed in the value of PropertySource if it(**@PropertySource**) exits in whereever in the app.

```
.
├src
| └main
|   └resources
|     └myproject.properties
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set inline properties using `SpringApplicationBuilder`:

```
SpringApplicationBuilder()
  .properties("spring.config.name=myproject")
  .sources(MyApplication.class)
  .run(args);
```

Comment: it's missing `new` in `new SpringApplicationBuilder()`

Comment: Didn't worked for me. I end up using `@PropertySource`

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure if this is the best approach (if a Spring guru sees this, please let me know if it is :), but I did the following:

`@PropertySource(value={"classpath:my-project.properties"}, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)`

Comment: This doesn't change the name of the `application.properties`, it adds a new property source to the environment. You ask a misleading question, then post a different answer and accept it, it's like a monkey scratching its own back :)

Comment: Fair point - I've changed the accepted answer :)

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar this is the perfect solution I guess because `spring.config.name` didn't worked for me 

Answer (score 0):

You can also provide the following System properties (or environment variables) to change the behavior:

- `spring.config.name` (`SPRING_CONFIG_NAME`): Defaults to an application as the root of the file name.
- `spring.config.location` (`SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION`): The file to load (such as a classpath resource or a URL). A separate Environment property source is set up for this document and it can be overridden by system properties, environment variables, or the command line.

```
$ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties
```